# Concrete5: Why single pages do not automatically get the active theme applied to them?

Tags: concrete5

I am working on 5.6.3.4. Just curious to learn why the single pages do not automatically get the active theme applied to them. It looks like I have to manually map the single pages to a theme inside the `/config/site_theme_paths.php` file or am I missing something? So everytime I create a new site I have to do the mapping for all single pages in `/config/site_theme_paths.php`. Not sure how it's done in 5.7 but that's a bit of a pain.

Answer (score 0):

The only Single Pages you have to map with the /config/site_theme_paths.php are the System single pages (Login/Register/etc) the rest will use the view.php in your theme as the wrapper automatically.  This is the same with 5.7 I believe.